# Azure spot instance deallocated regardless of bid. Identical non-spot instance runs fine

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm

The listed spot price is $0.06/hour, when creating the VM but the history shows an average of $0.15 at the peak, so I made my price/capacity bid $0.25. (Normal non-spot price is $0.35/hour.) It's immediately deallocated on startup. So I tried again as a test to set it to $1.00/hour, 3x the normal non-spot rates, and the same exact think happens.

I don't see anything in the activity log about deallocation and don't know if/where to look to find specifics of a deallocation reason. There's no error message while I watch the provisioning

I created an identical non-spot VM and it runs fine.

As a side note, I'm in the US on a pay-as-you-go subscription, but every region says my instance is not available on my subscription (NV4as_v4). However I can create onein the Central India region, so it doesn't seem like an inherent limitation to my subscription, and there's no option I can find to debug the subscription type/upgrade/etc. Looking in quotas shows I should have more than enough to create these & higher end instances as well.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard back from Azure support. They confirmed that my quotas were fine, and told me they are deprecating their GPU instances, and this is a symptom of that process. And also why (separate from my original question above) almost no NV* instances were available at all, even though they were listed: They are listed because they are not fully deprecated and are still used by other customers, but new instances for customers who didn't previously provision them are limited.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using Azure spot instance   At any point in time when Azure needs the capacity back, the Azure infrastructure will evict Azure Spot Virtual Machines. VMs can be evicted based on capacity or the max price you set. When creating an Azure Spot Virtual Machine, you can set the eviction policy to Deallocate (default) or Delete.

The amount of available capacity can vary based on size, region, time of day, and more. When deploying Azure Spot Virtual Machines, Azure will allocate the VMs if there is capacity available, but there is no SLA for these VMs. Azure Spot Virtual Machine offers no high availability guarantees. At any point in time when Azure needs the capacity back, the Azure infrastructure will evict Azure Spot Virtual Machines with 30 seconds notice

FYI-Azure Spot Virtual Machines will have a separate quota pool. Spot quota will be shared between VMs and scale-set instances.if you require additional quota you will be able to submit the request to increase your quota for Azure Spot Virtual Machines